# a non anti-pattern approach to remove an item in an array of components in React

Tags: reactjs

The attached code is a list of countdown timers, each of which I would like to remove upon reaching 0.  I'm using splice and understand that this will not work as this results in index reference inconsistencies, but I was wondering if it's more advised to keep all the element in the array intact and simply flag the ones that have reached 0.  But then in flagging the ones to not render, I keep the old items when I'd like to remove them.  Any help would be much appreciated.  The fiddle can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/b3btz0ye/

```
class Time extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      timeLeft: `${Math.floor(props.seconds/60)} minutes left`
    };

    this.timerId = null;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.countdown(this.props.seconds);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerId);
  }

  countdown(seconds) {
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds/60);
    this.timerId = setInterval(() => {
      seconds--;
      if (seconds <= 0) {
          clearInterval(this.timerId);
          this.props.die();
      }
      if (seconds < 60 && seconds >= 0) {
          this.setState({timeLeft: `${seconds} seconds left`});
      }  else if (seconds % 60 === 0) {
          minutes--;
          this.setState({timeLeft: `${minutes} minutes left`});

      }
    }, 1000);
  };

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.timeLeft}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      five: 5,
      list: [{
        seconds: 5
      }, {
        seconds: 10
      }, {
        seconds: 15
      }]
    };
    this.el = null
  }
  handleClick() {
    console.log('clicked ', this.state.five);
    this.setState({five: this.state.five + 5});
  }
  die(i) {
    var temp = this.state.list;
    temp.splice(i, 1);
    this.setState({list: temp});
  }
  render() {
    console.log('app render');
    return (
      <div>
      <div>The app</div>
        {
          this.state.list.map((item, i) => {
    return <Time die={this.die.bind(this)} key={i} seconds={item.seconds} />
          })
          }
      <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Reset</button>
        </div>

      );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the following problems in your code.

1. The state in `<App/>` contains the seconds for each of the `<Time/>` components. But once these are passed to the component, the state is never updated.
2. The `Time` component has 2 states, one passed from App as props and
   the other stored in the component a state. This will create problems during updates and renders. Since the text that is stored in the state of the `Time` component can be derived from the state that is passed in as props, it should be calculated and set in the render method itself.
3. The different `Time` components have to be distinguished based  on index, which is never a good idea. React optimizes the way it mounts and unmounts arrays of components. In this case, whenever a `Time` is removed from the the array, the last component will always be unmounted, even when we pass a different index. React will then re render the components from the new array. This is why `splice` will not work.
4. The logic for reducing the number of seconds is giving unexpected results.

I have fixed the above issues by

1. Making the `Time` components stateless and adding props for time updates which changes the state in the `App` component.
2. Adding an id to each of the data elements representing a `Time` component.
3. Updating the logic for reducing the seconds.
4. Removing the call to `clearInterval` in the `die` method and only calling it from `componentWillUnMount`.

Below is the code: (https://codesandbox.io/s/422jo3p2mx)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Time extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            timeLeft: `${Math.floor(props.seconds/60)} minutes left`
        };

        this.timerId = null;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.timerId = setInterval(() => {

            if (this.props.seconds === 0) {
                this.props.die(this.props.id);

            } else {
                this.props.setTime(this.props.id, this.props.seconds - 1);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.timerId);
    }



    render() {
        let { seconds} = this.props;
        let timeLeft = "";
        if (seconds < 60 && seconds >= 0) {
            timeLeft = `${seconds} seconds left`;
        } else {
            let minutes = seconds / 60 - seconds % 60;
            if (seconds % 60 === 0) minutes--;
            timeLeft = `${minutes} minutes left`;
        }
        return (
            <div > {timeLeft} </div>
        );
    }
}


class App extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                five: 5,
                list: [{
                    id: 10,
                    seconds: 5
                }, {
                    id: 11,
                    seconds: 10
                }, {
                    id: 12,
                    seconds: 15
                }]
            };
            this.el = null
        }
        handleClick=()=> {
            console.log('clicked ', this.state.five);
            this.setState({
                five: this.state.five + 5
            });
        }
        die = (i) => {
            var temp = [...this.state.list];
            temp = temp.filter(x => x.id !== i);
            this.setState({ list: temp });
        }
        setTime = (id, time) => {
            let temp = [...this.state.list];
            let timer = temp.find(x => x.id === id);
            timer.seconds = time;
            this.setState({list: temp});
        }
        render() {
            console.log('app render');
            return ( <div>
                        <div> The app </div> 
                        {this.state.list.map((item, i) => {
                                    return <Time key={i} id={item.id} seconds={item.seconds} die = {this.die} setTime={this.setTime}/>})
                        } 
                        <button onClick = {this.handleClick} > Reset </button> 
                    </div>
                );
            }
        }

        ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. I had tried replacing your `let temp = [...this.state.list]` with `let temp = [].concat(this.state.list)` to help with performance per the benchmark here http://jsben.ch/wQ9RU and doing that only seemed to update the seconds value once and after that, even though setInterval would execute everything in it every second, it would do so without having the updated value of seconds.  I was wondering why copying the array using concat would have a different result from using the spread operator.